# Prevent Stripe API from saving duplicate cards on customer

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I allow users to add new cards during the checkout. What happens is that the paymentIntent uses the 'setup_future_usage' option, which automatically attaches the payment method to the customer.

```
await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        customer: customer_id,
        setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
        amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
        currency: items.currency.toLowerCase()
      })
```

The problem with this is that it means that the user can enter the same card multiple times, and stripe will attach them all as individual cards to the user. I tried to take off 'setup_future_usage', but it gave me an error when trying to confirm payments saying that the payment wasn't attached to the customer. Does anyone know of a way within the Javascript SDK of making it so Stripe won't save duplicate cards on a per customer basis?

Comment: can you query their cards first and then only call the create method if the card hasn't been added yet

Comment: I cant query the card because I am using the CardElement from stripe.js. For now, I am just letting stripe make duplicates of the cards, although I would like to explore another method in the future. The explanation I was given implies that some people may want a different shipping/billing address therefore stripe allows the cards to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `fingerprint` prop https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/object#card_object-fingerprint can be used to check if the card already exists.

Comment: How would the OP be able to use this from the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

I chose a non-sophisticated approach to solve this - make an API call to "detach" all payment methods except the new one that was just setup.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/detach

I don't know that you could effectively pre-match the card data prior to creating the card in Stripe with the Elements API. It may be possible but this basic approach worked for me.